# paredit-forward-up won't cross line boundary

Tags: evil, paredit

`(a b (c |d) e f)`

`C-M-n` works as I would expect, producing this:

`(a b (c d)| e f)`

But if I break the line after the (c d) like so…

```
(a b (c |d)
     e f)
```

The same `C-M-n` does absolutely nothing. Interestingly, the command works as expected if I insert an end of line space just after `(c d)`. Given that the whole point of paredit is to edit syntax trees rather than text, I don't see how the insertion of a newline should have any impact on the behavior of paredit-forward-up.

What am I missing?

Comment: I can't replicate this problem (in Emacs 24.5 with paredit-version 25).

Comment: @phils: Where does point move for you? What version of emacs and paredit? I'm using paredit 25beta in emacs 24.5.1.

Comment: @phils: Ah! I think I may have figured out the problem: I'm using evil-mode. When I disabled evil-mode, the issue went away.

Comment: Consider reporting the behavior as an Evil bug or needed enhancement, if you think it appropriate.

Comment: @Drew: Ok. I notice there's an evil-paredit package, so perhaps I should be using that in lieu of plain paredit…

Comment: If you find an answer to your question, please consider posting it.